# StackBlitz - share url with specific path

Tags: stackblitz

I've created a small project on StackBlitz.
Link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/response-validation-docs

And this leads us to project with embedded browser on the right with url:
https://response-validation-docs.stackblitz.io
However I would like share it that I have such url with extra path in embeded browser :
https://response-validation-docs.stackblitz.io/nested-validation
Is that anyhow possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and seems there are many ways to accomplish this, the simple and straight forward is to use the query string parameters under the request URL.

To share the embedded link so it can go with the extra path mentioned you need to add the [`initialpath`](https://developer.stackblitz.com/docs/platform/embedding#:%7E:text=initialpath) option on your link so it would be:

**https://stackblitz.com/edit/response-validation-docs?file=src/app/app.component.ts&initialpath=nested-validation**

More information about this on the documentation:
[StackBlitz Docs- Embedding](https://developer.stackblitz.com/docs/platform/embedding/)